# Django User Creation

Tags: python, django

I am doing a basic user creation using the built-in UserCreationForm in Django.

Here is my views.py:

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username)
            if raw_password:
              user.set_password(raw_password)
            else:
              user.set_unusable_password()
            user.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':  form})
```

However, after registering a user and being redirected to home, the number of Users seen in my Admin page has not changed; no User has been created.
Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The indentation in your question is wrong. Fix it, as it could be causing the problem.

Comment: Ok, that was the obvious indentation, but I don't see a way of `redirect` happening without `User.objects.create_user` happening, and I think that should always either create a user or raise an exception. Oh, and you don't need to call `set_unusable_password`, it's called when the password is empty in `create_user`. Also, the indentation in the final `return` should be a level up, for when the form is invalid. Finally, you don't need to call `user.save()`, `create_user` saves the user.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you need anything other than `form.save()` and `redirect`, because [you're not doing anything that the form doesn't do](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a96b981d84367fd41b1df40adf3ac9ca71a741dd/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L64). Regardless, that doesn't explain your problem, it should be raising an exception rather than redirecting home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user=User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            user.save()
            #Below 2 lines, if you want user to get logged in
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':  form})
```

Comment: Tried this.. still no new User created when I view the User model in the admin page

Comment: @SkillaPop, Have a check now I have updated my answer

Comment: @SkillaPop You keep saying "when I view the User model in the admin page". Are you sure the user isn't being created? Could it be a filter in the Admin hiding it? Check in the console with `User.objects.count()`.

Comment: I just checked `User.objects.count()` and it remains the same number before I complete the Registration form

Comment: Yes, just did.. Same thing, no objects are created in the User model.

Comment: Check it using console. If user can be created from there using  [user createion from shell link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010177/create-user-from-the-command-line-in-django/46010380#46010380)

Answer (score 0):

don't know why you can redirected to home with no use create,but you should deal with the situation form is not vaild and remove form.save() from form.is_valid() block like:

```
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # remove form.save()
    ....
else:
    print(form.errors.as_text())
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':  form})
```

---

or override save method for UserCreationForm like i do:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

the full demo is:

```
from django.views.generic import *
class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_messages = {
        'duplicate_username': u"duplicate username",
        'password_mismatch': u"password_mismatch",
        'duplicate_email': u'duplicate email'
    }

    username = forms.RegexField(
        max_length=30,
        regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
        error_messages={
            'invalid': u"onlay can contaions symbol @/./+/-/_",
            'required': u"required"
        },
        label='username'
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(
        error_messages={
            'invalid': u"email invalid",
            'required': u'required'},
        label='email'
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        error_messages={
            'required': u"required"
        },
        label='password1 '
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        error_messages={
            'required': u"required"
        },
        label='password2'
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email")

    def clean_username(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["duplicate_username"]
        )

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages["password_mismatch"]
            )
        password_validation.validate_password(password2)
        return password2

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["duplicate_email"]
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Is there any way I wouldn't have to add this into my own forms.py? Im just using the built in form

Comment: yes, you can do this staff in form.is_vaild() block like you do now,but you need to handle form invaild

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are saving the object so many times. As documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/#UserCreationForm), when calling *form.save()* in a *UserCreationForm* instance, Django will create the user, set the password (which comes from the *password1* field), save the instance in the database and return the user for you. So *User.objects.create_user* and *user.save()* will only save the object again.

Parhaps it's not the solution for your problem but have you tried just like this:

```
def user_register(request):
   form = UserCreationForm() 
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          user = form.save()
          # if you want to authenticate your user or log any info, do it here
          return redirect('home')
   # I wouldn't use the else statement here, so if there are errors in the form you probably want the same template to be rendered, in order to show the form errors to your user.
   return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':  form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everybody that helped me think this through. It seems, of course, the answer was much simpler than I thought. My new `user_register` view is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def user_register(request):
   form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       return redirect('home')
   else:
       return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':   form})
```